# Access web application from android with NFC feature

Tags: android, web, nfc, smartcard

I have developed web application to read/write NFC, for card reader i am using ACR122U. Now i want to access my web application from android application by using card reader from android device.

Is it possible if i still use web application? or i must develop again with native application android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your Web app is talking to the reader (presumably some ActiveX, etc. is exposing an API to PC/SC), but Android doesn't give you direct access to the NFC reader. You have to implement an activity that gets notified when a tag comes in range. In short, your Web app most probably won't work as is.

You can use something like this present the phone as an external reader to your server, but it requires custom firmware:

https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/BTPCSC

Comment: I'm using library java (javax.smartcardio) for talking to the reader, and now it's work. Is webview in android can resolve my prob?

Comment: Ah, so you want to run the web page (client) on Android? Really depends on what you are doing, but you could probably hook something up using `JavaScriptInterface`. However, you still won't have control, your app will only be called when someone touches a tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching the same thing. Have you tried PhoneGap's NFC plugin? http://phonegap.com/2011/09/26/building-an-nfc-enabled-android-application-with-phonegap/

I have not used PhoneGap before and have not had good feedback from people who did. Let me know how you get along if you choose this option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bridge javascript into Android code, then write all the layer that will handle the tag. I suggest you use Android NFC APIs directly, not PCSC, because Seek's PC/SC will not be able to target your tag, it is meant for secure elements (embedded, SD, SIM) and not for driving tags. Depending on your tag's technology, the code might look quite different, but you might be able to reuse some of your code.

The phonegap approach might work (depending on how well the adaptation layer handles your tag, but seems limited, and will impose some code changes on you web application.